# Accessing result field from array elements of structs after thread has completed execution

Tags: c, multithreading, struct

The aim of the program is to determine the average of 12 float numbers using threads.

The idea is to use threads and have each thread perform the same amount of computation in order to generate the result.

I planned on having 6 threads, each adding 2 of the float numbers. Once all threads are complete, add all the results together in `main` and then divide by 12.

I create a `struct` called `args`, which passes 2 of the numbers into a thread. And another field which will contain the result of that addition, in order to expose the result for consumption in `main`.

I cant seem to access the `result` field, from each `struct` inside the `subsetsOfNumbers` array.

Error:

```
error: member reference type 'struct args' is not a pointer; did you mean to use '.'?
    totalSum += subsetsOfNumbers[thread]->result;
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
                                        .
1 error generated.
```

Program code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int thread_count = 6;

struct args {
    float firstNumber;
    float secondNumber;
    float result;
};

void *child_add(void *input) {

  struct args *data=((struct args*)input);

  float firstNumber = data->firstNumber;
  float secondNumber = data->secondNumber;

  data->result = firstNumber + secondNumber;

  return NULL;
}


int main() {

  long thread;
  pthread_t *thread_handles; // array of pthread structures
  struct args *subsetsOfNumbers; // array of args structures

  float numbers[12] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0};
  int index = 0;

  thread_handles = malloc(thread_count * sizeof(pthread_t));
  subsetsOfNumbers = malloc(thread_count * sizeof(struct args));

  for (thread = 0; thread < thread_count; thread++) {
    struct args *subsetOfNumbers = (struct args *)malloc(sizeof(struct args));
    subsetOfNumbers->firstNumber = numbers[index++];
    subsetOfNumbers->secondNumber = numbers[index++];
    subsetsOfNumbers[thread] = *subsetOfNumbers;

    pthread_create(&thread_handles[thread], NULL, child_add, (void *) subsetOfNumbers);
  }

  float totalSum = 0;

  for (thread = 0; thread < thread_count; thread++) {
    void *partialSum;
    pthread_join(thread_handles[thread], NULL);
    totalSum += subsetsOfNumbers[thread]->result;
  }

  float average = total / 12.0;

  free(thread_handles);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That error message tells you what you are doing wrong, what is confusing about it?

Comment: What is `subsetsOfNumbers`? If it's a pointer (essentially a dynamic "array" of `args` structures), then what is `subsetsOfNumbers[thread]`?

Comment: `subsetsOfNumbers` is "a dynamic 'array' of args structures)" as you say. `subsetsOfNumbers[thread]` is assigning each element of the array with a new `struct args` instance

Comment: Turns out using `.` instead of `->` worked. I had gotten a different error using `.` due to the function `child_add` being declared in a separate file `duplicate symbols`, which made me think `.` wasn't working.

Comment: OT:  regarding: `float numbers[12] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0};`  The array is declared as type `float` however, the actual literal values are of type `double`.   Suggest: `float numbers[12] = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f, 7.0f, 8.0f, 9.0f, 10.0f, 11.0f, 12.0f};`  Notice the trailing `f` on each 'float' literal

Comment: besides the `->` instead of `.` the posted code contains several other problems, like the variable `total` not being declared.  When compiling, always enable the warnings then fix those warnings.   ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce that same output.

Comment: OT: regarding statements like: `thread_handles = malloc(thread_count * sizeof(pthread_t));`  Always check the returned value (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==NULL) then call `perror( "malloc failed" );`  then cleanup, the call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  The `perror()` outputs both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.  That way, the user is informed of the error

Comment: regarding: `void *partialSum;
    pthread_join(thread_handles[thread], NULL);
    totalSum += subsetsOfNumbers[thread]->result;`  Suggest: 1) at the end of the thread, exit via: `pthread_exit( &threadSum );`  2) in the main function: `long totalSum = 0;`  and `for( i = 0; i<threads; i++ ) {  int  threadSum; `pthread_join(thread_handles[thread], &threadSum); totalSum += threadSum; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error suggests:

```
totalSum += subsetsOfNumbers[thread].result;
```

Worked.

I had gotten a different error using `.` due to the function `child_add` being declared in a separate file `duplicate symbols`, which made me think `.` wasn't working.